# In the Book of Enoch, what is meant by the ram in Parable of the Animals?

Tags: jesus, apocalyptic, 1-enoch

In the [Book of Enoch](http://scriptural-truth.com/images/BookOfEnoch.pdf), there is a long parable of animals, representing many Biblical figures such as Cain and Abel, David and Saul, Solomon, etc. I would like to make sense of part this parable; who is the Ram? I don't think it's Jesus because of Jesus' portrayal as a sacrificial lamb. Also I don't think he gains "the big horn" nor opens his eyes ("their eyes were opened") nor is Jesus characterized as a "sheep" or "ram" in any other passage. I would incline Jesus to be the man who is writing these things down about the shepherds and the sheep as well.

Could this ram with the big horn possibly be the one that Jesus spoke of when he said

> “Who then is the faithful and wise manager, whom the master puts in charge of his servants to give them their portion at the proper time? **Luke 12:42 BSB**

Anyways, here is an excerpt from the parable/vision of the animals that speaks about that ram.

> 90.8 And I saw in the vision, how the ravens flew upon those lambs, and
>   took one of those lambs, and dashed the sheep in pieces and devoured
>   them.
>
> 90.9 And I looked until horns came up on those lambs but the ravens cast
>   their horns down. And I looked until a big horn grew on one of those
>   sheep, and their eyes were opened.
>
> 90.10 And it looked at them and their eyes were opened. And it cried to the
>   sheep, and the rams saw it, and they all ran to it.
>
> 90.11 And, besides all this, those eagles, and vultures, and ravens, and
>   kites, were still continually tearing the sheep in pieces, and flying upon
>   them and devouring them. And the sheep were silent but the rams 
>   lamented and cried out.
>
> 90.12 And those ravens battled and fought with it, and wished to make
>   away with its horn, but they did not prevail against it.
>
> 90.13 And I looked at them until the shepherds and the eagles, and those
>   vultures, and kites, came and cried to the ravens that they should dash the
>   horn of that ram in pieces. And they fought and battled with it, and it
>   fought with them and cried out so that its help might come to it.
>
> 90.14 And I looked until that man, who wrote down the names of the
>   shepherds and brought them up before the Lord of the sheep, came, and he
>   helped that ram and showed it everything; its help was coming down.
>
> 90.15 And I looked until that Lord of the sheep came to them in anger, all
>   those who saw him fled, and they all fell into the shadow in front of Him.
>
> 90.16 All the eagles and vultures and ravens and kites, gathered together
>   and brought with them all the wild sheep, and they all came together and
>   helped one another in order to dash that horn of the ram in pieces.
>
> 90.17 And I looked at that man, who wrote the book at the command of the
>   Lord, until he opened that book of the destruction that those last twelve
>   shepherds had wrought. And he showed, in front of the Lord of the sheep,
>   that they had destroyed even more than those before them had.
>
> 90.18 And I looked until the Lord of the sheep came to them and took the
>   Staff of His Anger and struck the Earth. And the Earth was split. And all
>   the animals, and the birds of the sky, fell from those sheep and sank in the
>   earth; and it closed over them.

Comment: Check the Zech 11 in the Septuagint interlinear translation especially 11:7 to get the key as to how Enoch maps onto canonical Bible https://biblehub.com/interlinear/apostolic/zechariah/11.htm

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there is no way one can be absolutely certain whom the original author of 1 Enoch intended to be represented by the great horn. Robert Henry Charles, who produced an English translation of 1 Enoch in 1893, commented on p. [251](https://books.google.com/books?id=vwA3AAAAMAAJ&pg=PG251#v=onepage&q&f=true),

> 9. The horned lambs, as we have seen, must be the Maccabees, and in the “great horn’ it is impossible to find any other than Judas Maccabaeus.

Again, on p. [253](https://books.google.com/books?id=vwA3AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA253#v=onepage&q&f=true),

> 16. The first great Messianic victories of Israel are the signal for the final assault of all the Gentiles combined with the apostate Jews (i.e. the sheep of the field) against Israel. Israel is still led by Judas, the great horn.

---

**References**

[*The Book of Enoch.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vwA3AAAAMAAJ) Trans. Charles, Robert Henry. Oxford: Clarendon, 1893.

Comment: Thanks for the sources and answer. However, Judas never received any consolations or knowledge from the "man" in the Parable nor did the "Lord of the sheep" come down in anger during the Maccabean revolt era.

Comment: +1, Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

The ram with the "great horn" in 1 Enoch is beyond a shadow of a doubt our Lord Jesus Christ. For instance, their word for ram in other translations denotes the ram as the "leader of the sheep". Jesus said,
"My sheep listen to my voice; I know them, and they follow me."-John 10:27.
The scene played out in this passage is the Messiah's return, when Jerusalem is assailed by the Gentile nations for a final time in the battle of Armageddon but the Lord (Jesus) will stand on the Mount of Olives and destroy Israel's enemies, the last trumpet will sound and all the rams (Christians) will have their "eyes opened" and gather to their leader (the ram) pertaining to the resurrection when all the believers will be caught up and gathered from the four winds of the earth along with this confederate of Jewish Christians who repent and mourn over the one whom they have pierced (Zechariah 12:10). This battle of Armageddon will last 40 years according to the War Scroll.

Enoch 89:12-15

> <sup>**12**</sup> I saw also, that horns grew upon those lambs; and that the ravens lighted down upon their horns <sup>**13**</sup> I saw, too, that a large horn sprouted out on an animal 1 among the sheep, and that their eyes were opened <sup>**14**</sup> He looked at them Their eyes were wide open; and he cried out to them <sup>**15**</sup> Then the dabela saw him; all of whom RAN to him.

The antichrist and his Gentile armies will attempt to destroy the ram (Jesus).

Enoch 89:16-20

> <sup>**16**</sup> And besides this, all the eagles, the avest, the ravens and the kites, were still carrying off the sheep, flying down upon them, and devouring them The sheep were silent, but the dabela lamented and cried out <sup>**17**</sup> Then the ravens contended, and struggled with them <sup>**18**</sup> They wished among them to break his horn; but they prevailed NOT over him <sup>**19**</sup> I looked on them, until the shepherds, the eagles, the avest, and the kites came <sup>**20**</sup> Who cried out to the ravens to break the horn of the dabela; to contend with him; and to kill him But he struggled with them, and cried out, that help might come to him

After this battle ensues, the archangel Michael will come down to assist the armies of light in this battle against the antichrist and his armies as mentioned in Daniel,

> And at that time shall Michael stand up, the great prince which standeth for the children of thy people: and there shall be a time of trouble, such as never was since there was a nation even to that same time: and at that time thy people shall be delivered, every one that shall be found written in the book. (Daniel 12:1 KJV)

Enoch 89:21-22

> <sup>**21**</sup> Then I perceived that the man (archangel Michael) came who had written down the names of the shepherds, and who ascended up before the Lord of the sheep <sup>**23**</sup> He brought assistance, and caused every one to see him descending to the help of the dabela (Jesus).
>
> <sup>**23**</sup> I perceived likewise that the LORD(Jesus) of the sheep came to them in wrath, while all those who saw him fled away; all fell down in his tabernacle before his face; while all the eagles, the avest, ravens, and kites assembled, and brought with them all the sheep of the field.

Then the antichrist and his armies after having gathered in the battle of Armageddon will attempt to destroy the Lord Jesus, in fact, Jesus quotes Enoch to establish this point,

> Wherefore if they shall say unto you, Behold, he is in the desert; go not forth: behold, he is in the secret chambers; believe it not. For as the lightning cometh out of the east, and shineth even unto the west; so shall also the coming of the Son of man be. For wheresoever the **carcase** (Jesus) is, there will the **eagles** (Gentile armies) be gathered together. (Matthew 24:26-28)

Enoch 89:24-26

> <sup>**24**</sup> All came together, and strove to break the horn of the dabela(Jesus) <sup>**25**</sup> Then I saw, that the man(Archangel Michael), who wrote the book at the word of the Lord, opened the book of destruction, of that destruction which the last twelve shepherds wrought; and pointed out before the Lord of the sheep, that they destroyed more than those who preceded them <sup>**26**</sup> I saw also that the Lord (Jesus) of the sheep came to them, and taking in his hand the sceptre of his wrath seized the earth, which became rent asunder; while all the beasts (Gentile kingdoms) and birds of heaven (Gentile peoples) fell from the sheep (elect in Jerusalem), and sunk into the earth, which closed over them.
>
> <sup>**27**</sup> I saw, too, that a large sword was given to the sheep, who went forth against all the beasts of the field to slay them <sup>**28**</sup> But all the beasts and birds of heaven fled away from before their face <sup>**29**</sup> And I saw a throne erected in a delectable land;

The Millenial Kingdom begins.

Answer (score 0):

The ram with the one horn is none other than the apostle John in one of his reincarnations, who has been tarrying on the earth waiting for the arrival of Jesus Christ. According to Revelations, he was given the seven thunders and was told he must prophecy to nations, tongues, peoples, etc. His work isn't done until he has uttered the seven thunders, pertaining to the seven congregations and the completion of its number which is the seventh congregation and the seventh number. John received the seven thunders in his old age and was told he will prophecy to nations, tongues, and people's. Clearly, this work would continue on for lifetimes. To be a sheep means to be of Israeli descent and phenotype as can be noted in the prophecy of the animals and in observation of human phenotypes. The Eagles are of Dinaric descent (Roman descent) as noted by their phenotype. Ravens are perhaps Gracile Mediterranid, and then there are the Vultures and Kites. Clearly, in the days before the coming of Michael, the archangel, there is a revived Roman Empire. Michael, the angel of the Lord, who knows the hidden name which no one but he knows, as according to the book of Enoch and the book of Revelation where Jesus Christ is the one who knows the name which no one else knows, is none other than Jesus Christ himself and will come to the aid of the Israelites and those who have faith in him. The beginning of Daniel 12 marks the second coming.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with your explanation of the dabela. If you look closely at the messages of the prophets, especially Isaiha, Daniel, Elijah, Jeremiah, and Ezekiel, you can clearly see that the end will come because ALL of God's people have forgotten Him due to a false prophet. ALL will have idols and images which are blasphemy to God. The old book says that there is only one God with no others beside Him. They predicted that the Romans (the 4th beast) would destroy the earth (soil/ ground), but have they? The 4th beast will get all to bow to him and worship him, he will be like the most high. Who is that beast? In Enoch, it says that the evil ones will write books about their lies.  Who are they and what books? The righteous or elect will be given books near the end and their eyes will be open so that they see the path of righteousness and wisdom will be given to them and they will open their eyes to the truth.
The maccabees died with their innocence rather than eat swine. They fought righteous battles with the pagans who tried to get them to follow their idols. History has been defiled and what we think we know to be facts are actually fiction.  Cyrus was the Messiah who freed God's people, but after him it gets blurry with Alexander and the Romans. The deception is great and terrible. The 4th beast will change the ordinances, times and laws. Think about that.  Who has changed God's laws and declared even swine okay to eat and encourages the drinking of blood and eating of his body in rituals? Who got rid of the Sabbath and changed the calendar by altering the order of the months? Where did the 7 year and 70 year jubilee go when all debt is forgotten and the soil rests. We are supposed to celebrate 4 times per year and give glory to God for all that he has created and given to us. Those months are 1, 4. 7 and 10; first of spring, summer, fall and winter. They all signify specific times of life and death of God's creation. 7 days each,  3 before and after and 1 as the main event. The 10th month celebration was morphed into Christmas because the pagans couldn't get God's true followers to celebrate their sun God,  Sol, so they made the son (sun) of God, over time and reinforced it by writing a story about it to decieve many for generations. The ashera pole is now the Christmas tree, the wreath is not what it seems and if people knew what it symbolizes,
they wouldn't hang them up so liberally. Trees are significant to God and are mentioned in the bible numerous times. Why? Think about the number of people that have to forget about God in order for his wrath to come and destroy the whole world. What do most people believe?  What does He consider to be backsliding children? (they say my name on their lips but have me far from their hearts) Look at what is going on in the world and how much time has passed. Enoch tells the entire plan from beginning to end. There are 10 weeks,  each week is 1000 years. We are somewhere in the 7th or 8th week.  So use wisdom of God and who He is to reevaluate who is the christ and who is the anti christ and what their actual roles are. Look and the ground you are standing in before you dig your heals in too deep. Read Isaiha 66:17 carefully.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).